# Single photon detection problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, cavity-qed, rabi-model

In 1999 the Haroche group in Paris performed the measurement of a single photon without destroying it. The experimental setup comprises a standard cavity-quantum-electrodynamic (cavity-QED) setting: an atom is coupled to the electromagnetic field in a cavity. The basic Hamiltonian of such a system reads ($\hbar$ = 1)
\begin{align}
\mathcal{\hat{H}}
&  = \omega_c \hat{a^\dagger} \hat{a} + \omega_g |g\rangle \langle g| + \omega_e |e\rangle \langle e| + \omega_f |f\rangle \langle f| + \frac{i \Omega} {2} (|e\rangle \langle g| + |g\rangle \langle e|) (\hat{a} - \hat{a}^{\dagger} )
\\ & \qquad + if(t) (|f\rangle \langle g| - |g\rangle \langle f|),
\end{align}
where $\hat{a}$ denotes a photon annihilation operator, $|g\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$, $|f\rangle$ are the three states of the atom. The first line describes the free energy of the system, while the second line denotes the interaction of the atom and the electromagnetic field. The transition between the states $|g\rangle$ and the state $|f\rangle$ is driven via a classical light field of the form: $f(t) = 2 \alpha \cos(\omega_d t + \phi), (\alpha, \omega_d , \phi \in \mathcal{R})$

> 1. Show that in an appropriately chosen interaction frame and after a rotating wave approximation the Hamiltonian becomes
>    $$
>    \mathcal{\hat{H}^{'}} = \Delta |f\rangle \langle f| + \frac{i \Omega} {2} (|e\rangle \langle g| \hat{a} - |g\rangle \langle e| \hat{a^{\dagger}}) + i \alpha \left(|f\rangle \langle g| e^{-i\phi} - |g\rangle \langle f|  e^{+i\phi} \right)
>    $$
>    with $\Delta = \omega_f - (\omega_g + \omega_d)$. The second interaction describes a swapping of excitations between the atom and the photonic field, while the last term induces oscillations between $|g\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$.

Can someone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read carefully our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. In its current form, this question is just asking us to do your work for you. What parts of the exercise are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can you give a reference for the body of your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Energy in interaction hamiltonian and energy levels in pump probe experiments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589017/energy-in-interaction-hamiltonian-and-energy-levels-in-pump-probe-experiments)